# Determine if a tableview cell is visible

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to know if a tableview cell is currently visible?
I have a tableview whose first cell(0) is a uisearchbar.
If a search is not active, then hide cell 0 via an offset.
When the table only has a few rows, the row 0 is visible.
How to determine if row 0 is visible or is the top row?

Comment: [Swift Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804935/1634890)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`UITableView` has an instance method called `indexPathsForVisibleRows` that will return an `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath` objects for each row in the table which are currently visible.  You could check this method with whatever frequency you need to and check for the proper row.  For instance, if `tableView` is a reference to your table, the following method would tell you whether or not row 0 is on screen:

```
-(BOOL)isRowZeroVisible {
  NSArray *indexes = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
  for (NSIndexPath *index in indexes) {
    if (index.row == 0) {
      return YES;
    }
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Because the `UITableView` method returns the `NSIndexPath`, you can just as easily extend this to look for sections, or row/section combinations.

This is more useful to you than the `visibleCells` method, which returns an array of table cell objects.  Table cell objects get recycled, so in large tables they will ultimately have no simple correlation back to your data source.

Comment: thank you! it was very helpful, but it should be "indexPathsForVisibleRows" not "indexPathsForvisibleRows"

Comment: Thanks for this answer.Star is missing.  "for (NSIndexPath *index in indexes) {"

Comment: Note that instead of using a `for` statement to loop thru all the indexes in the array, if you are looking for the row of index 0 of section 0, it is probably easier to directly write `BOOL isRowZeroVisible = [[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:0 inSection:0]];`

Comment: in reference to @AliSoftware's comment, it should now say indexPath*For*Row

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows

Comment: Note that in viewWillAppear, you might get false positives from `indexPathsForVisibleRows` as layout is in progress

Comment: if anyone wants to check the cell type instead of the row, use `cell isKindOfClass:[YourClassCell class]`

Answer (score 51):

To checking tableview cell is visible or not use this code of line

```
    if(![tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:newIndexPath])
    {
       // your code 
    }
```

here newIndexPath is IndexPath of checking cell.....

**Swift 3.0**

```
if !(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(newIndexPath)) {
  // Your code here

}
```

Comment: You would have to unwrap the optional first in swift.

Answer (score 17):

I use this in Swift 3.0

```
extension UITableView {

    /// Check if cell at the specific section and row is visible
    /// - Parameters:
    /// - section: an Int reprenseting a UITableView section
    /// - row: and Int representing a UITableView row
    /// - Returns: True if cell at section and row is visible, False otherwise
    func isCellVisible(section:Int, row: Int) -> Bool {
        guard let indexes = self.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
            return false
        }
        return indexes.contains {$0.section == section && $0.row == row }
    }  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work until entire cell is visible. If even a small(tiniest) part of cell is not visible, this will return false

Answer (score 6):

Swift Version:

```
if let indices = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    for index in indices {
        if index.row == 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
}
return false
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (which can also be used to check if a row is fully visible) would be to check if the frame for the `row` is inside the visible rect of the `tableview`.

In the following code, `ip` represents the `NSIndexPath`:

```
CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
if (cellFrame.origin.y<tableView.contentOffset.y) { // the row is above visible rect
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
else if(cellFrame.origin.y+cellFrame.size.height>tableView.contentOffset.y+tableView.frame.size.height-tableView.contentInset.top-tableView.contentInset.bottom){ // the row is below visible rect
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
}
```

Also using [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) should work, since it returns a `nil` object if the row is not visible:

```
if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip]==nil){
  // row is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift:**

Improved @Emil answer

```
extension UITableView {
    
    func isCellVisible(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        guard let indexes = self.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
            return false
        }
        return indexes.contains(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that "Somewhat visible" is "visible". Also, in viewWillAppear, you might get false positives from `indexPathsForVisibleRows` as layout is in progress, and if you're looking at the last row, even calling `layoutIfNeeded()` won't help you for tables. You'll want to check things in/after `viewDidAppear`.

This swift 3.1 code will disable scroll if the last row is fully visible. Call it in/after viewDidAppear.

```
    let numRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) // this can't be in viewWillAppear because the table's frame isn't set to proper height even after layoutIfNeeded()
    let lastRowRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: numRows-1, section: 0))
    if lastRowRect.origin.y + lastRowRect.size.height > tableView.frame.size.height {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    } else {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

IOS 4:

```
NSArray *cellsVisible = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSUInteger idx = NSNotFound;
idx = [cellsVisible indexOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    return ([(NSIndexPath *)obj compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame);
}];

if (idx == NSNotFound)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best to check by Frame**

```
let rectOfCellInSuperview = yourTblView.convert(yourCell.frame, to: yourTblView.superview!) //make sure your tableview has Superview
if !yourTblView.frame.contains(rectOfCellInSuperview) {
       //Your cell is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2023 simple solution, for a given index path:

```
tableView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(cellIndexPath)
```

Comment: It doesnt care if the top view is seem half.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that `indexPathsForVisibleRows` doesn't take tableView **insets** into account. So for example if you change insets on keyboard appearance, rows covered by keyboard still are considered visible. So I had to do this:

```
func isRowVisible(at indexPath: IndexPath, isVisibleFully: Bool = false) -> Bool {
    let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let cellY = isVisibleFully ? cellRect.maxY : cellRect.minY

    return cellY > tableView.minVisibleY && cellY < tableView.maxVisibleY
}
```

And this is UITableView extension:

```
extension UITableView {

    var minVisibleY: CGFloat {
        contentOffset.y + contentInset.top
    }

    var maxVisibleY: CGFloat {
        contentOffset.y + bounds.height - contentInset.bottom
    }
}
```