# How to detect UITableView scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableView` which can contain different number of cells.

So I would like to show top & bottom arrows (like on the picture below) if `UITableView` has hidden cells on top or bottom and hide them if all `UITableView`'s cell are visible.

[image]

I have implemented `UIScrollView` delegate method to detect UITableView's scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

}
```

but don't know how to check if first or last cell is not visible.

**EDITED**

Here is the solution:

```
        if (self.ingredientsTableView.contentOffset.y<0){
            [ingrUpArrow setHidden:YES];
        }
        else if (self.ingredientsTableView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
            [ingrUpArrow setHidden:YES];
        }
        else if (self.ingredientsTableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.ingredientsTableView.contentSize.height - self.ingredientsTableView.bounds.size.height)) {
            [ingrUpArrow setHidden:NO];
            [ingrDownArrow setHidden:YES];
        }
        else {
            [ingrUpArrow setHidden:NO];
            [ingrDownArrow setHidden:NO];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many useful properties of UItableView which can be used in such cases and `tableView.contentOffset.y` is one of it. Use it. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326658/determine-if-a-tableview-cell-is-visible) can be useful.