# Animation works if UITableView scrolled gently, doesn't work when scrolled fast

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm blinking a label inside a custom `UITableViewCell` using this code:

```
-(void) startBlinker
{
    [self stopBlinker];
    self.edgeCaseLabelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(blinkEdgeCaseLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.edgeCaseLabelTimer
                                 forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}


-(void) blinkEdgeCaseLabel
{
    if (blinkCycle == 0)
    {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.thisCustomCell.edgeCaseLabel duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            self.thisCustomCell.edgeCaseLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        } completion:nil];

        blinkCycle = 1;
    }
    else if (blinkCycle == 1)
    {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.thisCustomCell.edgeCaseLabel duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            self.thisCustomCell.edgeCaseLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } completion:nil];

        blinkCycle = 0;
    }
}
```

I expect there's more elegant and modern code around for this, but it works. At least it works as long as I don't scroll the TV hard. Gently, works fine. Fast, the label remains (when it comes to rest) in one (or the other) of the states and doesn't blink.

The only cells affected are the top and bottom cells (which are the only ones with blinking labels, not coincidentally).

I've tried using `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to bump it into action again, but no dice.

Any ideas?

**Note:** I'm testing this on simulator & not on a device.

**Edit:**

Following @Woodstock's suggestion I switched to a regular NSTimer. In addition, I incorporated this code:

```
-(BOOL)topOrBottomCellIsVisible
{
    NSArray *indexes = [self.myTableview indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    for (NSIndexPath *index in indexes)
    {
        if (index.row == 0)
        {
            return YES;
        }

        if (index.row == detailFRC.fetchedObjects.count - 1)
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

from @Devunwired, contributed in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326658/determine-if-a-tableview-cell-is-visible). I put this method in several critical locations related to appearing and scrolling.

Now things seem more robust, but I think @Fahim Parkar is probably onto something with it running on the sim instead of a device. I say "more robust" rather than "cured" because while the blinking seems more resistant to fast scrolling, it still doesn't start automatically upon initial appearance of the cell(s) in question. I'll report back when I try it on the device.

Comment: check on device... I believe it will work properly,,,

Comment: I was wondering that myself. However, I haven't quite got to that point--provisioning, etc. Thanks!

Comment: You're adding your already scheduled timer to a run loop. You shouldn't use a scheduled timer if you are manually adding to the run loop. Instead use a regular nstimer.

Comment: Thanks to both commenters! Please see my edit above for results.