# How to highlight/change background color of table view section header while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, sectionheader

I am stuck with displaying the table view section header. Problem is, when I scroll down, until I **hit** the **next section header**, I want my **previous section header** to be **highlighted** and **as soon as** I hit the **next section header**,I want my this **"new" section header** to be **highlighted** and my **previous section header** to be **unhighlighted**. That, namely, means that I want the header which is displayed at the top to be highlighted while I scroll down and up.

To be more clear, I put related pictures:

[image: 1.Current section header is "Section 1"]
1.Current section header is "Section 1" This occurs when app starts.

[image: 2.Scrolled down but current section header is still same]
2.Scrolled down but current section header is still same and should remain so until next section header commences.

[image: 3.Scrolled down and passed to next section header.]

3.Scrolled down and passed to next section header. This section header should be highlighted since it is at the top of table view now.
I put these pictures by taking snapshots and filling red color by using a painting tool. I hope it is clear to understand.

Comment: Why? Do you think a non-standard user interface is going to make users like your app? I don't think so.

Comment: Actually, it is not in my hands. They asked me to do so. I searched a lot but could not figure out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhabs you can do it with a trick?

[Determine if a tableview cell is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326658/determine-if-a-tableview-cell-is-visible)

Just take a look which cells are visible. If a cell of section 2 is visible but no cell of section 1, you know section 2 is at the top.