# How to check if a cell has been displayed Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

When I display my tableview I've made my cells come with an animation like this.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

             cell.alpha = 0
             let rotation = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 20, 0)
             cell.layer.transform = rotation
             UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9){
             cell.alpha = 1
             cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

    }
```

It's working like this but when i go down and then up again to see the previous cells the animation still exists.

Show I believe I have to check if the cell has been displayed.

Something I try is to use didEndDisplayingCell function and put the cell.tag inside an array and then I was checking if the current cell is inside that array with array.contains(cell.tag) but it didn't work. 
Actually the animation worked only for the three first cells and then nothing.

Comment: use visibleCells for getting visible cells.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326658/determine-if-a-tableview-cell-is-visible

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for your answer but I want to know which cells have been seen so the animation will not be used again to cells that have been seen

Comment: Add the cell indexPath to your array instead of tag, the cells are being reused, so the tag will be the same for the reused cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep an array of indexPaths, adding to it whenever a cell is displayed. This way you can check if the cell has already animated.

```
if (!indexPaths.contains(indexPath)) {
    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    cell.alpha = 0
    let rotation = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 20, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = rotation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9){
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. It worked!
I will accept your answer in 3 minutes

Answer (score 1):

As @James-P mentioned in comments - just create an array

```
var indexPathArray = [NSIndexPath]()
```

and rewrite your willDisplayCell method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if !indexPathArray.contains(indexPath) {

        indexPathArray.append(indexPath)

        cell.alpha = 0
        let rotation = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 20, 0)
        cell.layer.transform = rotation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9){
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is put the indexpath of cell in an array and check if the indexpath is in array.if the indexpath is in array dont perform animation