# Determine if a cell in on screen and perform a function

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want to find out if a cell is displaying onscreen in a table view.

I tried out `willDisplay` method but it's of no use. I even tried

```
if (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPath))! {
                    print("showing now")
}
```

This function works, But it doesn't print anything when the cell is on screen or as I scroll down. Ex: If I have 5 cells, As the app launches and the cell are on the display, nothing is printed. Also, when I scroll from cells 1 to 5, Nothing is displayed. On contrary, If I scroll back from cells 5 to 1, It will display it, which completely defies my purpose.

I hope you understood my query and can help me with an apt solution.

Cheers!

Comment: show your tried code willDisplay should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`willDisplay` method of tabView should work for you.

Give `DataSource` and `Delegate` properly. `Control+drag` from `TableView` to yellow icon will display you correct options.

[image]

Add extension to `ViewControllerClass` and confirm table protocols-:

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 2
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row
        return cell!
    }

    // will display prints while displaying cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("visible now")
    }
```

Comment: Well, I had called this method earlier. It didn't quite work. It somehow is working now.

Comment: Also, is there a way by which i can print "visible row" only if it is completely visible and not partially.

Comment: @AakashDave this will help you-:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326658/determine-if-a-tableview-cell-is-visible/3326891

Answer (score 0):

Remember to connect `UITableView`'s `delegate` property and conform to `UITableViewDelegate`.

Try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("cell \(indexPath.row) is about to display")
}
```

from `UITableViewDelegate`'s protocol. Documentation could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview).